# HP bar with variable js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress

I want make enemy hp bar with progress function. Its part of my code :

```
    function clickRandom(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;   
} 
    function monster() {
            mjaki();
            if (level === "forest") {
                mlvl = clickRandom(1, 100);
                    if (mlvl <= 40) {
                        mname = "(LVL 1) "+monsname+" Orc";
                        mxp = 60;
                        mgold = clickRandom(2, 8);
                        maxmhp = 50;
                        mhp = maxmhp;
                    }

                    if (mlvl <= 70 && mlvl > 40) {
                        mname = "(LVL 2) "+monsname+" Orc";
                        mxp = 70;
                        mgold = clickRandom(4, 10);
                        maxmhp = 65;
                        mhp = maxmhp;
                    }

                    if (mlvl <= 90 && mlvl > 70) {
                        mname = "(LVL 3) "+monsname+" Orc";
                        mxp = 80;
                        mgold = clickRandom(6, 12);
                        maxmhp = 80;
                        mhp = maxmhp;
                    }

                    if (mlvl <= 100 && mlvl > 90) {
                        mname = "(BOSS) "+monsname+" Orc";
                        mxp = 100;
                        mgold = clickRandom(8, 14);
                        maxmhp = 100;
                        mhp = maxmhp;
                    }
            }

            if (level === "desert") {
                mlvl = clickRandom(1, 100);
                    if (mlvl <= 40) {
                        mname = "(LVL 1) "+monsname+" Troll";
                        mxp = 120;
                        mgold = clickRandom(10, 20);
                        maxmhp = 150;
                        mhp = maxmhp;
                    }

                    if (mlvl <= 70 && mlvl > 40) {
                        mname = "(LVL 2) "+monsname+" Troll";
                        mxp = 130;
                        mgold = clickRandom(12, 22);
                        maxmhp = 280;
                        mhp = maxmhp;
                    }

                    if (mlvl <= 90 && mlvl > 70) {
                        mname = "(LVL 3) "+monsname+" Troll";
                        mxp = 140;
                        mgold = clickRandom(14, 24);
                        maxmhp = 310;
                        mhp = maxmhp;
                    }

                    if (mlvl <= 100 && mlvl > 90) {
                        mname = "(BOSS) "+monsname+" Troll";
                        mxp = 170;
                        mgold = clickRandom(16, 26);
                        maxmhp = 350;
                        mhp = maxmhp;
                    }
            }

            //miejsce na kolejne poziomy narazie forest


        }
            $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
              value: mhp
            });
```

Its working but my mhp is random number for example 60 , 80, 100, 120, 110 etc... and when the 
mhp is changing progress bar is not full.

// So what should i use to do this if not progress ?

Comment: "*I cant paste all my code [because] [it's] too many lines.*" Two things: **first:** you're not charged per character, or line, in your question, it's *all free!* and, **second:** this is why we ask for a [*minimal* example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) to reproduce your problem, *not* the entirety of your code-base.

Comment: `mhp` can only be between 0 and 100, because it is a percentage. And @DavidThomas is right, you should provide a simplified version of the code that is causing you trouble, in order for us to see where the problem is.